# Laravel 4 connection between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables:

1. Items table which has id, name, color_id. *color_id references id on items table*
2. Colors table which has color and id. (e.g. purple with id=1)

When i want to add a new item and user uses purple color on item i want that color to be saved as *color_id = 1*  on items table. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure you can do that. At first you can query to `Colors` database so that you can get the `id` of color. Then you can insert that id to `Items` table. This is a general way. But as you are using Laravel 4, you can do this smartly by using Eloquent. Check out this point of laravel doc: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Thank you ! So the logic is I need to get the color input then get  id of color  and save it to items table

Comment: If this helps you, please approved & give upvote to my answer. Best of luck.